# How to limit smartsheet-api to some specific sheets and not all the sheets in a workspace

Tags: smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2, smartsheet-java-sdk-v2

If I have two sheets (for example) in a workspace then how do I limit an API access token to one of those sheets so that only that particular sheet can be updated from the API and the other sheet will not be visible to the API?

I have searched the documentations from smart-sheet but could not find the information.

Answer (score 0):

An API access token will be able to access whatever items in Smartsheet that the user who owns the token can access. So, to restrict an access token such that it can be used to access only certain items requires that you restrict what its owner can access.

By default, any user that is shared to a workspace can access all items in the workspace. However, it’s possible to instead grant a user access only to specific individual items in a workspace (instead of 'sharing' an entire workspace with the user, which would grant them access to everything in the workspace). See this article for more info on that: https://help.smartsheet.com/articles/520104-share-sheets-reports-dashboards#Workspace_Sharing.

Comment: Share and API access are two different things right? Do I have to set an access token as well as owner for it and then set access limit for the owner of the access token?

Answer (score 0):

You have to share the second sheet to a second account. Then generate/get a token for the second account and perform the API calls under the second account.

Depending on the operations performs the second account may have to be ADMIN of the second sheet.

Comment: In that case does the second account has to be a Business/Individual account or a free account?

Comment: Depends on your requirements, but most of them could be achieved by a free account.